# How to select MYSQL rows which are not '0'?

Tags: mysql

I am filtering my database in Wordpress using:

```
$count = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(rid) FROM $table_name WHERE rid = ( SELECT id FROM $table_name WHERE pid = '%s' AND activated != 0 )", $pid ) );
```

Currently `$count` is `4` while it should be `3`, as the last entry in my database is `activated = 0` as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

Yellow = the targeted rows, while the last one should be filtered as its `'0'` and not be counted.

`%s` is a variable for a `pid` (personal ID) which is received by a string `?pid=123…`. This does work and is not the problem, as all of the yellow rows belonging to the example pid (green one) are counted.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Have you tried `... IS NOT NULL`? `0`, `'0'`, `''`, and `NULL` are four different things.

Comment: Seeing `$table_name` in the FROM clause makes me *cringe*. Use the keyword `AND` to combine two boolean conditions. e.g. the clause  `WHERE t.pid='1' AND t.activated = '0'` will returns rows only if *both* of the  conditions evaluate to TRUE. As far as testing for inequality, you can use either the pattern of negating an equality comparison ... `AND NOT (t.activated='0')`, or you could use the inequality comparison operator, either `AND t.activated <> '0'` or `AND t.activated != '0'`. The `IS` keyword is reserved for testing NULL values... e.g. `t.foo IS NULL` or `t.foo IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: I could move the `$table_name` outside of this selector and call it using `t.activated`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(rid) FROM $table_name WHERE rid = ( SELECT id FROM $table_name WHERE pid = '%s' AND activated != 0 )", $pid ) AND activated != 0
```

add this **AND activated != 0** to end of your rid ()

Comment: Thanks! It was the position of my inserted `activated != 0`, as I have checked the green row, while I should have checked the yellow rows from my example image.

Answer (score 1):

There's a big difference between `NULL` and things like empty strings or `0` integers. The `IS NOT` operator is used for `NULL` comparisons since `NULL=NULL` is false.

You should do:

```
activated=0
```

Or this:

```
activated IS NOT NULL
```

If you allow `NULL` in that column you may need to test against both the `0` and `NULL` state, or instead flip it around and to this:

```
activated!=1
```

Comment: Thanks @tadman, I have edited my question to be more clear. To be honest my question is how to combine a `WHERE` condition with another. In jQuery I can use `&&`, how can I combine my statement with your suggestions?

Comment: You combine things in SQL with `AND` which is analogous to `&&`. I'm not sure why you're asking this as you use `AND` in your second query.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have updated my question to be more detailed, as I did not got the code to work.

Answer (score 1):

if activated is numeric you should use

```
SELECT id FROM $table_name WHERE pid = '%s' AND activated <> 0
```

or if is a string

```
SELECT id FROM $table_name WHERE pid = '%s' AND activated <> '0'
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have updated my question to be more detailed, as I did not got the code to work.

Comment: @MarianRick   ... but Looking to your sample image  you have no rows with  pid = '%s'  .. what do you mean with this condition ? .. please explain better ..

Comment: I have updated my question to explain `%s`, while I know that this part is working, as all yellow lines are counted (which are too much, as I want to filter the last yellow one, because its `activated = 0`.

Comment: @MarianRick   could you show me the content of your var ' %s'  and the data type for activated ? and why you are using %s instead of $s?

Comment: To be honest I can't tell, its a given code I try to expand out of prelaunchr https://github.com/raftco/wp-prelaunchr It works now. What caused an error was the wrong position of `activated != 0` as @AKZhang has suggested.

Comment: @MarianRick   i'm sorry but seems you have already solved your problem 6 hours ago ....  so way you are commening me?

Comment: I have solved it 24mins ago and then wrote my last comment. I appreciate your help, thanks for that, and I am happy it is solved :)

Answer (score 1):

If you compare [value]=NULL in SQL, the result is NULL.

So when you want to filter all rows where activated is not '0' then you should do like this:

```
SELECT id FROM $table_name WHERE pid = '%s' AND activated IS NOT '0' OR activated IS NULL
```

other solution can be:

```
SELECT id FROM $table_name WHERE pid = '%s' AND COALESCE(activated,'NULL')  <> '0'
```

Comment: To be more precise: an equality comparison to a NULL value always evaluates to NULL. It never evaluates to FALSE. And the expression `IS NOT '0'` will return a syntax error. (The `IS` keyword is reserved for comparison to `NULL`.... valid usage: `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`). Once that problem is fixed in the first query, the `AND` operator has higher precedence than `OR`... rows that satisfy the condition after the `OR` will not be required to satisfy the first condition, before the `AND`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I have updated my question to be more detailed, as I did not got the code to work.